# Is there a Postgres SQL function that allows me to store the result of each row to be used in the next row?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have the following table in PostgresSQL, and I would like to find a function or logic to store the result of the first row in a new column to be used in the second row and so on.

The formula is (stock + pending-sells), so for the first row, the result is "2," and that should become my new stock value for the second row. Therefore, the result is 2 + 0 + 0 = 2. For the next row (row 3), my new stock is (2 + 1 - 0), resulting in 3, and the same with the following rows.

Is there a way to achieve this with SQL, or do I need to try outside with Python?

| idx | date | ID | stock | pending | sells |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-07-01 | 187760 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2023-08-01 | 187760 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2023-09-01 | 187760 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2023-10-01 | 187760 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023-11-01 | 187760 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 2023-12-01 | 187760 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I tried with lag() and lead() with no luck so far.

The "expected result" column with the formula (stock+pending-sells) for this table

| idx | date | ID | stock | pending | sells | expected_results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-07-01 | 187760 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-08-01 | 187760 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 2023-09-01 | 187760 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 2023-10-01 | 187760 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2023-11-01 | 187760 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | 2023-12-01 | 187760 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

The "expected result" column is calculated by considering the result of the previous row's calculation as the new stock for the next row.

I tried with this

```
with cte_ as
(
SELECT 
nc.date,
nc.id,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY nc.id ORDER BY nc.date ASC) AS ranking,
nc.stock,
nc.pending,
nc.sells,
nc.stock + nc.pending - nc.sells AS formula
FROM test_table nc 
where nc.id='187760'
)
select *,
lag(c.formula) OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY c.date),
lag(c.formula) OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY c.date)+c.pending-c.sells as test
from cte_ as c
```

But the result column is

| results |
| --- |
| NULL |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 0 |

Thank you.

Best regards.

Comment: See the window function lag

Comment: _I tried with lag() and lead()_ Show us what you tried...

Comment: I need to point out that doing this kind of analysis is very easy in Python.  There may be a convoluted and difficult-to-maintain solution in SQL, but in my view it's better to have the database store the DATA, and do your computations in code.

Comment: In your expected result, why does the `stock` column always show a value of 1?

Comment: Thank you Tim for your comment, I'll try with a dataframe

Comment: You're right, Mike. There should be the result from the previous row. I edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to do simple arithmetic calculations like this outside of the database.

It is wrong to have the `stock` column populated with the value `1` in your table.  If you are recalculating stock based solely on movements, then you need a starting value that you apply your movements to.  Most systems use the current (perpetual) inventory as the starting point and calculate backwards.

I used it as the initial stock level with `first_value()`.

```
select idx, date, id, 
       coalesce(
         first_value(stock) over w1 
           + sum(pending) over w1
           - sum(sells) over w1
         , stock) as stock,
       pending, sells,
       first_value(stock) over w2 
         + sum(pending) over w2
         - sum(sells) over w2 as expected_result
  from test_table
window w1 as (partition by id order by date
              rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
       w2 as (partition by id order by date);
```

Working [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jy9S4kqc)

Comment: Thank you, Mike. It's working great! I'll learn more about those functions; they are very useful for these cases. Fiddle is also helpful to show queries, by the way, I didn't know it. Regards

Answer (score 1):

The following query returns the results as shown in the original post:

```
WITH t(idx, date, id, stock, pending, sells) AS (
  VALUES (0, '2023-07-01'::date, 187760, 1, 1, 0),
         (1, '2023-08-01'::date, 187760, 1, 0, 0),
         (2, '2023-09-01'::date, 187760, 1, 1, 0),
         (3, '2023-10-01'::date, 187760, 1, 0, 1),
         (4, '2023-11-01'::date, 187760, 1, 0, 0),
         (5, '2023-12-01'::date, 187760, 1, 0, 0))
SELECT idx, date, id, stock, pending, sells,
       stock + sum(pending) OVER stock_group - sum(sells) OVER stock_group AS expected_results
  FROM t
  WINDOW stock_group AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY idx)
  ORDER BY idx;
```

This query uses `sum` as a window function with an implicit window frame of `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` to aggregate `pending` and `sells` to be added the current `stock`.

This query addresses the revised post:

```
WITH t(idx, date, id, stock, pending, sells) AS (
  VALUES (0, '2023-07-01'::date, 187760, 1, 1, 0),
         (1, '2023-08-01'::date, 187760, 1, 0, 0),
         (2, '2023-09-01'::date, 187760, 1, 1, 0),
         (3, '2023-10-01'::date, 187760, 1, 0, 1),
         (4, '2023-11-01'::date, 187760, 1, 0, 0),
         (5, '2023-12-01'::date, 187760, 1, 0, 0))
SELECT idx, date, id,
       stock + coalesce(sum(pending) OVER stock_group_prior - sum(sells) OVER stock_group_prior, 0) AS stock,
       pending, sells,
       stock + coalesce(sum(pending) OVER stock_group_current - sum(sells) OVER stock_group_current, 0) AS expected_results
  FROM t
  WINDOW stock_group_prior AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY idx ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
         stock_group_current AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY idx)
  ORDER BY idx;
```